# Capturing trace statements with DebugView

Tags: iis, debugview

I have a web app that's running in IIS. I have added some `Trace.WriteLine` statements to allow me to debug issues in prod like environments. I am trying to use DebugView utility to monitor those trace statements. If I try to set the `Capture Global Win32` it gives me an `error Unable to monitor Win32 debug output: Access is denied`.

I tried running DebugView in elevated mode by right-clicking and choosing "Run as administrator" menu, but I am still getting the same error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you running debugview locally or from a network location?